# Resolve local webserver to public domain

Tags: freebsd, webserver, jails

Is there a way to forward traffic on mydomain.com to local web server hosted on virtual machine ( bhyve )?

Let's say my local machine has local IP - **1.1.1.1**

And my registered domain in X hosting company is with IP - **3.3.3.3**

How can I forward the traffic from 3.3.3.3 to my local virtual machine?

Comment: is this IP `1.1.1.1` public or private address?

Comment: @RomeoNinov it is private. The public IP I have is from the domain provider.

Comment: No, the piblic address from your internet provider

Comment: @RomeoNinov lets say the vm ip is 1.1.1.1 and the ISP IP is 2.2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

If your public IP is 2.2.2.2 you should set in your domain provider this IP to be [www.yourdomain.tld](http://www.yourdomain.tld) (replace with your domain). This will redirect requests to http(s)://www.yourdomain.tld to your server.

Do not forget to redirect the port(s) you use (80,443) from internet faced interface (2.2.2.2) to your local IP (1.1.1.1) in your router (if you use such). And permit on firewall (if activated) on your computer the same ports.